# Replace elements of list between specified elements into another

Tags: python

If I have 2 lists:

```
listA = ['A','B','C','D','B','D','A','C']
listB = ['C','B','A','B','C','A','A','C','D','A','B']
```

How would I want to replace all elements in between `'B','C'` and `'D','A'`, `listA[1 to 6]` with the elements in between the same characters of `listB`, `listB[3 to 9]`.

so that listB would end up as:

```
listB = ['C','B','A','B','C','D','B','D','A','B']
```

and listA would end up as:

```
listA = ['A','C']
```

I've created a simple loop that checks for 'B','C' and 'D','A' and returns the indexes in which they occur at:

```
for i in range(len(gene1)):
    if listA[i] == 'B':
        if listA[i+1] == 'C':
            return I
```

However that won't work if the letter sequences change in characters or length.

Comment: So how did you define the indices to replace? By searching for the pairs `'B', 'C'` and `'D', 'A'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to slices; if you do so for both objects, you can swap those chunks *in place*:

```
listB[3:10] = listA[1:7]
listA[1:7] = []
```

This first replaces everything in the `listB[3:10]` slice with all values referenced in the `listA[1:7]` slice. `listB` is adjust in length as needed.

If you also need to figure out where the start and end points are, you'd have to scan first:

```
def find_markers(l):
    start, stop = 0, 0
    # iterate over a sliding window; current and next element
    second = iter(l)
    next(second, None)
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(l, second)):
        if (a, b) == ('B', 'C'):
            start = i
        elif (a, b) == ('D', 'A'):
            end = i + 2
            return start, end  # exit early

a_start, a_end = find_markers(listA)
b_start, b_end = find_markers(listB)
listB[b_start:b_end] = listA[a_start:a_end]
listA[a_start:a_end] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings and [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) can help to solve such problems :

```
#conversion  L -> S
strA, strB = [ ''.join(list) for list in [listA,listB] ] 

# split
import re
A1,A2,A3 = re.split('BC|DA',strA)
B1,B2,B3 = re.split('BC|DA',strB)

# conversion S -> L
listA = list( A1 + A3 )  
listB = list( B1 + 'BC' + A2 + 'DA' + B3 )
```

And clearly shows what you are doing.